# How to assign a ticket to a user based on the priority of the ticket in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I have a requirement on a project that a ticket which is a `Blocker` should be assigned to `ABC` user, ticket which is a `Major` should be assigned to `DEF` user, so on.

Has anyone implemented a worfklow in JIRA which does something like this? I know you can design a workflow which can assign a ticket to the user based on the type of the ticket but based on the priority can you assign a ticket to a user? Please help.

Comment: This seems off-topic. Is it in any way a coding question? If not, it should be at [sf].

Answer (score 0):

JIRA comes with components and component leads, and if you leave the assignee at Automatic then the newly created issue will be assigned to the appropriate component lead. I'm not sure what you mean when you say that JIRA can assign based on issue type.

Assigning according to Priority means that you have to trust the person setting the priority. Also, you have to be able to configure the mapping from Priority to Assignee somewhere and then be able to change that mapping later on.

To assign according to priority I would use a custom Script Runner post function on the create transition of the workflow in use.

Comment: What I meant by `JIRA can assign based on the issue type` is that a workflow can be created in the JIRA which can assign a ticket to a particular person based on the type of the ticket. And I am trying to see if JIRA has a way to do the same with the priority.